# How to set checkbox default by Name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to set the checkbox checked by default with the name attribute not class or id ?

`<input type="checkbox" name="test">`

i tried this but doesn't work:

`document.getElementByName("test").checked = true;`

Please provide a jsfiddle.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. However, there is no `getElementByName` method, there is only `getElementsByName`. So if you have a single element with name `"test"`, you can do:

```
document.getElementsByName("test")[0].checked = true;
```

Otherwise, you can set an ID to the element and use `document.getElementById`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GKFcR/

Comment: i have this like a 100 attribute in a back-end file that, and i want to be all checked by default, that's why i want to put a jquery/js in the onload.js that i have to not search for that input, will it work?

Comment: just add it to the html? `checked="checked"`

Comment: @Wezly — `checked="checked"`, not `true`.

Comment: @Wezly as i said i don't want to search in files, i want to add a js to the onload js file o have

Comment: @Jimmy For a set of elements just do the iteration, as was done in **DEMO**.

Comment: @VisioN Great, thanks! what if for example i have `name="test[]"` is it the same ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.querySelector` to select by attribute in any modern browser.

```
document.querySelector('[name=test]').checked = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xpxHe/

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with jQuery

```
$('input[name="test"]').attr('checked',true);
```

or Jquery 1.7+ use `prop` method

```
 $('input[name="test"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jQuery or without:

```
$('input[name="test"]').prop('checked', true);
document.getElementsByName("test")[0].checked = true;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UZB5Y/1/

Your example did not work as the method is `getElementsByName` which returns an array of element.

Or if you control the HTML, you can just set them as checked on the server:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test">

<input type="checkbox" name="test2">

<input type="checkbox" name="test2">

--------------------

// by jquery

$("input[name='test']").attr('checked','checked')

// by javascript

document.getElementsByName("test2")[0].checked = true;
```

here is example : http://jsfiddle.net/85x74/

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery it is more simple :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test">
```

In jquery:

```
$('input[name="test"]').attr('checked','checked');
```

In javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName("test")[0].checked = true;
```